# How to delete files from directory on specific time, daily?

Tags: php, file, delete-file

My data.txt is generated each time when someone is visiting my site. I would like to delete this file on on specific time, let say 1:00AM daily.
I found this script but I'm struggling to update the code :/
Any advice?

```
<?php
  $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/files';
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ((time()-filectime($path.'/'.$file)) < 86400) {  // 86400 = 60*60*24
          if (preg_match('/\.txt$/i', $file)) {
            unlink($path.'/'.$file);
          }
        }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: what os? *nix => try using a cron job

Comment: Why would you want to do that with PHP? Use a cron job and delete the file with the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you posted deletes .txt files in the given folder if they are older than a day but the problem is that this test only happens once - when you run the script.

What you need to do is run this script periodically. If you are running this on Linux you should probably add a cron job that executes this script periodically, say once an hour or once daily.

If you're running this on Windows, there is a task schedule that you could use to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use task scheduler, such as [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for this purposes. You can remove your file simply via shell command

```
rm /path/to/data.txt
```

So there's no need to write a PHP script for that.